# HttpClient fails with Handshake Failed in Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: android, openssl, handshake

I am working on an android application which need to connect through HTTPS connection. But I got IOException - handshake failed.

What I have done is as below

First,using openssl to get server certificate chain

```
openssl s_client -connect www.bt.com.tn:443
```

And got

```
> CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=TN/ST=Tunis/L=TUNIS/O=Banque de Tunisie/OU=Direction de la monetique et du marketing/CN=online.bt.com.tn
   i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=TN/ST=Tunis/L=TUNIS/O=Banque de Tunisie/OU=Direction de la monetique et du marketing/CN=online.bt.com.tn
issuer=/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4573 bytes and written 328 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 59735BD9ABE9BBBA8F9B4041EAE4A25A47E6E125ADB3BBDEBD75C1CDDAA51551
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 06EE7455B1C0810E82B429E19FF400EFD8CF4052807F5AEDA52CA4BCBBD8A6DB6251ABB8FD49675624050B4A06920860
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1465465568
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
closed
```

Comment: Any solution for this problem !!

Comment: ***IOException - handshake failed*** is not much to go on. If you can provide more details, we may be able to help. You should probably provide some code, and provide at least the exact error message and some of the trace. I'm going to vote to close as seeking a tutorial on Android and HTTPS.